# WCF Routing/ESB Architecture?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, architecture, soa, n-tier-architecture

I've been working on building a set of enterprise services using WCF 4 within my organization and could use some guidance. The setup/architecture I've designed thus far is similar to a lightweight custom ESB. I have one main "broker" service (using wsHttp), that connects to three underlying netTcp services. Both the broker and underlying services share a common assembly that contains the model, as well as the contract interfaces. In the broker service I can choose which operations from the underlying services I want to expose. The idea is that potentially we can have a core of set of services and few different brokers on top of them depending on the business need. We plan on hosting everything (including the netTcp services) in IIS 7.5 leveraging AppFabric and WAS.

Here's my question, is such a design good practice and will it scale? These services should be able to handle thousands of transactions per day.

I've played around with the routing in WCF 4 in lieu of the broker service concept I've mentioned, however, have not seen much value in it as it just simply does a redirect.

I'm also trying to figure out how to optimize the proxies that the broker service (assuming this practice is advisable) has to the underlying services. Right now I simply have the proxies as private members within the brokers main class. Example:

```
private UnderlyingServiceClient _underlyingServiceClient = new UnderlyingServiceClient();
```

I've considered caching the proxy, however, am concerned that if I run into a fault that the entire proxy at that point would be faulted and cannot be reused (unless I catch the fault and simply re-instantiate).

My goal with these services is to ensure that the client consuming them can get "in and out" as quickly as possible. A quick request-reply.

Any input/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you have a handful of "backend" services, possibly on separate computers.  Then you have one "fontend" service, which basically acts like a proxy to the backend, but fully customizable in code.  We are doing this exact setup with a few computers in a rack. Our frontend is IIS7, backend is a bunch of wcf services on several machines.

One, will it scale?  Well, adding more processing power on the backend is pretty easy, and writing some load balancing code isn't too bad either.  For us, the problem was the frontend was getting bogged down, even though it was only acting as a proxy.  We ended up adding a couple more front end computers, "brokers" as you call them.  That works very well.  People have suggested that I use Microsoft ForeFront for automatic load balancing, but I have not researched it yet.

Two, should you cache the proxy?  I would say definitely yes, but it kind of sucks.  These channels DO fault occasionally.  I have a thread always running in the background.  Every 3 seconds, it wakes up, checks all the wcf services and wcf clients in the app. Any that are faulted get destroyed and recreated.

check host channels: ...

```
while(true)
{
  try{if(MyServiceHost.State!=System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened) {ReCreate();}} catch{} 
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

check client channels: ...

```
  private static ChannelFactory<IMath> mathClientFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMath>(bindingHttpBin);
  while(true)
  {
    try
    {
      if(MyServiceClient.State==System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted) 
      {
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(ub.Uri);
        ch = WcfDynamicLan.mathClientFactory.CreateChannel(ea);
      } 
    }
    catch{} 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
  }
```

On the client, I not only cache the channel, but also cache the ChannelFactory.  This is just for convenience though to make the code for creating a new channel shorter.